# How to combine EmbeddingBag and LSTM layers?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Python 3.9.6 Pytorch 1.9.0

I created a neural network with three layers, the first of which is EmbeddingBag and second- LSTM.

```
class PyTorchNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_dim, dropout):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
        
        #embedding layer
        self.embedding = nn.EmbeddingBag(num_embeddings = vocab_size, 
                                         embedding_dim  = embed_dim,
                                         sparse         = True)
        
        #lstm layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = embed_dim, 
                           hidden_size = hidden_dim, 
                           num_layers  = 1, 
                           dropout     = dropout)
        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dim, 
                            out_features=1)
        
        self.act = nn.Sigmoid()
        
        #init network small weights
        self.init_weights()  
      
    def forward(self, text, offsets):
        #text.shape    = torch.Size([363])
        #offsets.shape = torch.Size([64])
        embedded       = self.embedding(text, offsets)
        #embedded.shape= torch.Size([64, 32])
        _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(embedded)            #ERROR!!!
        dense_outputs  = self.fc(hidden.squeeze(0))
        outputs        = self.act(dense_outputs)
        return outputs
```

When I start training, the output from the first layer doesn't match in dimensionality to the input of the second layer. The program gives an error:

```
vocab_size = len(vocabulary)
embed_dim  = 32
hidden_dim = 16 
dropout    = self.DROP_OUT 
model = PyTorchNetwork(vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_dim, dropout).to(self.device)
predicted_label = model(text, offsets)
```

Full error trace:

```
> File "/Presentation/MixinButton.py", line 31, in _press_button_start
>     self.controller.perform_business_task()
> File "/ControllerPresentation/AController.py", line 16, in perform_business_task
>     result = self.perform_task()
> File "/ControllerPresentation/TuningPredictionModelController.py", line 36, in perform_task
>     return Initialization.ibusiness.tuning_prediction_model(self.signal_message, self.analysis_type, self.operation, self.severity_of_disease, self.print_only_final_results)
> File "/Business/IBusiness.py", line 35, in tuning_prediction_model
>     return self._perform_task(task)
> File "/Business/IBusiness.py", line 59, in _perform_task
>     task.run()
> File "/Business/TuningPredictionModelTask.py", line 27, in run
>     result = optimizator.learn(severity, silently=True)
> File "/home/ivan/eclipse-workspace/GompertzLaw/NeuralNetwork/PytorchOptimizator.py", line 94, in learn
>     self._train(train_dataloader, model, optimizer, epoch, silently)
> File "/NeuralNetwork/PytorchOptimizator.py", line 115, in _train
>     predicted_label = model(text, offsets)
> File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
>     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
> File "/NeuralNetwork/PyTorchNetwork.py", line 46, in forward
>     _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(embedded)
> File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
>     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
> File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 677, in forward
>     self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
> File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 620, in check_forward_args
>     self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
> File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 201, in check_input
>     raise RuntimeError( RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 2
```

How do I fix the error?

Comment: Please provide the **full error trace** as well as the shapes of your inputs.

Comment: I refreshed post with all necessary information.

Comment: What are the values of the sequence length and batch size?